# Xlwings take value from defined names

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have an excel with a defined name, cell A1 has assigned name "myName" is there a way with xlwings to take its content from its name rather than on its coordinates?

It should be the same of

```
    title, coord = next(wb.defined_names['myName'].destinations)
content = wb[title][coord].value
```

in openpyxls

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just do:

```
import xlwings as xw
xw.sheets[0].range('myName').value
```

See also: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#name

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was helpful and I was not able to find it. Do you know if there are ways to take it from the excel worksheet instead from the single sheet? In this case sheet[0]

Comment: from the workbook you mean? yes then you need to follow the link to see how the names collection work.

Comment: I mean without declaring the sheet. I was not able to make it work

Answer (score 3):

```
import xlwings as xw
content = xw.Range('myName').value
```

This avoids the positional reference to the sheet so that you can copy/paste your named range from one sheet to another as you build.

Answer (score 2):

Using xlwings, very similarly to VBA, you could use the following

```
range_object = wb.names("named_range").refers_to_range
range_value = wb.names("named_range").refers_to_range.value
```

As mentioned by Felix, the http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#name page has the answer. Unfortunately, there are no examples of how to access the named range without first specifying a worksheet. I hope my explanation helps.